# Why should I use this site instead of Ubuntu Ask/Shapado?

Tags: discussion

[Ubuntu Ask](http://ubuntu.shapado.com/) (hosted on [Shapado](http://shapado.com/)) looks just like an open-source clone of Ubuntu StackExchange.

Why should [I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devils_advocate) use one over the other?

Answer (score 15):

There are several reasons - first and foremost our question and user base far exceed that of Ubuntu Ask already. Secondly Shapado is a SAAS "rip" of the StackExchange software. The site software here is fully supported by the StackOverflow, LLC team and therefore receives regular updates and features pushes as well as support for bugs within the platform.

Outside of a larger/more active user base and question poll there is nothing stopping you from using both. However giving the publicity and current trends this StackExchange site will likely succeed in it's ventures whereas the Ubuntu Ask site appears to be dwindling.

## Stats

**Ubuntu.StackExchange**
1,028 Questions
2,195 Useres
96% Answered Questions

**Ubuntu.Shapado**
42 Questions
121 Users
N/A Answered Questions

I was unable to find the accept rate for the shapado site.

Comment: In the spirit of ubuntu and OSS should we not support that site then? Ok, sorry this is going to turn into flamebait. How does Shapado compare to StackExchange? Less features, no company backing, etc?

Comment: @DmitriyLikhten Less features, marketing, support, and - it's not "FOSS" (my apologies, wrong term) but [SAAS](http://shapado.com/plans). You have to purchase a plan, whereas this site costs nothing for us (the community) to run. This site exists because there was an interest in it on Area51 - not because someone is paying for it to exist.

Comment: Shapado.com is a subscription service, but the Shapado code is also published using the GNU Affero GPLv3. http://gitorious.org/shapado

Answer (score 5):

I have accounts on both. I prefer the AGPLv3 licensed Shapado (because Free Software needs Free Tools) but all the users are here, because of the crossover from StackOverflow.

Comment: Trying to visit the Ubuntu Ask website in Firefox results in a `Firefox can’t find the server at ubuntu.shapado.com.` message, and http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com says that ubuntu.shapado.com is down for everyone.