# StackExchange software open source?

Tags: discussion, design, stackexchange, legal

I like many things about the stack-exchange websites. Especially the editor I'm writing this post in and the tagging system. Is the software by any change available under an open license? I'd use it on personal sites, if it was allowed.

Partly I can answer my own question:
At least the [markdown editor](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) is available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See also:

- [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones/37953#37953)

Answer (score 3):

No it isn't.

[Why should I use this site instead of Ubuntu Ask/Shapado?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/302/why-should-i-use-this-site-instead-of-ubuntu-ask-shapado)

[How would #1 Bug would be fixed if AskUbuntu uses a Windows Platform?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/489/how-would-1-bug-would-be-fixed-if-askubuntu-uses-a-windows-platform)

Answer (score 1):

As other post have mentioned it is not open-source so you would need to look at the alternatives, such as [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/)